# Multipart email both text and HTML - Python

Tags: python, email, mailer

Following is the piece of code that I've used to send both text and HTML in an email. Is there a a better way?

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from mailer import Mailer
from mailer import Message
from smtplib import SMTP

def sendEmail(body, dfOutput):
    # Send the email to the list of users
    # this is exclusively using mailer libary

    message = MIMEMultipart()
    message['Subject'] = msgSubject
    message['From'] = msgFrom
    message['To'] = MsgTo
    html = "<p>" + body.replace("\n", "<br>") + "</p>"
    html = html + dfOutput
    message.attach(MIMEText(html, "html"))
    try:
        sender = smtplib.SMTP(smtpServer)
        sender.sendmail(message['From'] , message['To'], message.as_string())
    except:
        print ('Error in sending email.')
        pass

    print ('Email sent successfully')
```

Note: The above function works. However, wondering, is there a better way?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html

Comment: Thanks. Looks like there is an option to add text and html using msg.set_content() and msg.add_alternative(). Will experiment.